# Hamiltonian analysis of relational $N$-Particle Dynamics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, action, constrained-dynamics

I am following "A Shape Dynamics Tutorial, Flavio Mercati" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0105), and have problems understanding the hamiltonian formulation of $N$-particle dynamics as sketched on page 32 onward ("6.3 Application to our systems, Differential almost-Hamiltonian formulation").

No problem do I have with the lagrangian formulation as sketched on page 26 onward ("The Newtonian $N$-body problem"). Here I recapitulate the hamiltonian formalism, as I tried to follow it. We start with the lagrangian
\begin{align}
   S = &\int d\mathcal{L} = 2 \int \sqrt{E - V} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\sum_i m_i \| \mathfrak{D}q^i \|^2 },\tag{55}
   \cr
   \mathfrak{D}q^i =& dq^i + d\omega \times q^i + d\theta.\tag{56}
\end{align}
In Mercatis book (or preprint as linked above) it is not stated clearly, but I assume that we treat the variable $q^i$ as those with which we do the canonical analysis (deriving canonical momenta, doing Legendre transformations, Poisson brackets ... etc), whereas we leave $d\omega$ and $d\theta$ as spectators (or simple Lagrange multipliers) as far as the canonical analysis is concerned.
The canonical momenta are
\begin{align}
   p_i = \frac{\partial\ d\mathcal L}{\partial q^i} = \frac{m_a \mathfrak{D}q^a}{d\chi}.
\end{align}
This gives us immediately a primary constraint
\begin{align}
    H - E = 0, 
        \qquad\qquad
        H := \sum_a \frac{p_a^2}{2m_a} + V(q).
\end{align}
So far so good, but know I am getting confused. If I do a legendre transformation with respect to $dq$, I get as the canonical hamiltonian
\begin{align}
   \sum_i p_i\ dq^i\ - d\mathcal{L} = -d\theta \cdot P - d\omega \cdot L
\end{align}
with $P = \sum_i p_i$ and $L = \sum_i q^i \times p_i$. Incoorporating the primary constraint I get the total hamiltonian
\begin{align*}
    -d\mathcal{A} &= -d\lambda\ (H - E) - d\theta \cdot P - d\omega \cdot L.
\end{align*}
This, it seems to me, is (apart from a sign) the differential almost hamiltonian (as cited on page 32). Also I have changed notation: I write $d\lambda$ instead of $d\chi$. That is because I think at this stage of the dirac-analysis, $d\lambda$ is either arbitrary (gauge parameter) or will be constrained as a result of the diract consisteny algorithm. I has not yet the meaning of the "differential of the instant" (page 27)
\begin{align}
    d\chi := \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\sum_i m_i \| \mathfrak{D}q^i \|^2 }}{\sqrt{E - V}}. \tag{58}
\end{align}
As defined above, $d\chi$ depends upon the "velocities" $dq^i$, and those shall not appear explicitly in the hamiltonian. But somehow, the above expression for $d\chi$ should reappear in the hamiltonian anaylsis ?!

I hoped that it will appear through the dirac constraint analysis (constraints shall propagate), but sofar I only got
\begin{align*}
        0 = \lbrace H, -d\mathcal{A} \rbrace 
        &= d\omega \cdot \lbrace H, L \rbrace 
        + d\theta \cdot \lbrace H, P \rbrace \\
        &= d\omega \cdot \sum_a q^a \times \frac{\partial V}{\partial q^a} 
        + d\theta \cdot \sum_a \frac{\partial V}{\partial q^a}
    \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    0 = \lbrace \alpha P, - d\mathcal{A} \rbrace 
    &= -d\lambda \lbrace \alpha P, H \rbrace + d\omega \cdot \lbrace \alpha P, L \rbrace \\
    &= d\lambda\  \alpha \cdot \sum_a \frac{\partial V}{\partial q^a} + \alpha \cdot d\omega \times P
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    0 = \lbrace \alpha L, -d\mathcal{A} \rbrace 
    &= -d\lambda \lbrace \alpha L, H \rbrace + d\theta \cdot \lbrace \alpha L, P \rbrace \\
    &= d\lambda\ \alpha \cdot \sum_a q^a \times \frac{\partial V}{\partial q^a} 
    - d\theta \cdot \alpha \times P
\end{align*}
where $\alpha$ is simply a (3d)vector-constant, that avoids me to write vector-indizes.

And another thing that I don't understand: The above equation for the propagation of constraints seem to imply other constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_a q^a \times \frac{\partial V}{\partial q^a} = 0 \\
\sum_a \frac{\partial V}{\partial q^a} = 0.
\end{align}
But I do not remember them from doing the Lagrangian analysis?

Comment: More on [shape dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22shape+dynamics%22).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (hamiltonian) equation of motion give
\begin{align}
    dq^i = \lbrace q^i, d\mathcal{A} \rbrace = d\lambda\ \frac{p_i}{m_i} - 
    d\omega \times q^i - d\theta
\end{align}
Solving for $p_i$, putting that into the primary constraint
\begin{align}
    \sum_i \frac{p_i^2}{2 m_i} + V - E = 0
\end{align}
and solving for $d\lambda$ gives
\begin{align}
    d\lambda = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\sum_i m_i \|\mathfrak{D}q^i\|^2}}{\sqrt{E - V}}
\end{align}
as expected from the lagrangian formalism.

As to the secondary constraints, $\sum_i q^i \times \frac{\partial V}{\partial q^i} = 0$ and $\sum_i \frac{\partial V}{\partial q^i} = 0$:
They are nothing else than the statements that total momentum and angular momentum are conserved, using the equation of motion from the lagrangian:
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\mathfrak{D}p^a}{d\chi} &= - \frac{\partial V}{\partial q^a}
\end{align*}